# Are questions that require calculations off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I've asked a question about the recent solar eclipse (March 8-9, 2016) that requires some basic eclipse geometry calculations. Someone who does this will understand how to deal with the plane - I've added a simple map of the flight path. The two articles cited in the top line of the question mention that the large number of astronomers on that flight was no coincidence!

Simply put, an eclipse that's total in one place [can be annular in another place](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/849/7982) farther from the moon.

But the comments seem to be coming from people who think I don't know what I'm talking about. Is this question too hard, or is the calculation considered "original work" and therefore somehow off-topic?

Comment: "original work" is one of those Wikipedia things. No such rule applies on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow.